# what is the flow in this program?

Tags: cobol

I came across a piece of cobol program which got me confused, [this](http://home.swbell.net/mck9/cobol/style/alter.html) is the page containing the code, it try to demonstrate how bad ALTER is but at the same I don't understand the program flow.

```
     PERFORM 2100-PROCESS-RECORD THRU 2199-EXIT.
...
 2100-PROCESS-RECORD. 
     GO TO 2110-PROCESS-HEADER.
*
 2110-PROCESS-HEADER.
* code to process a file header
     ALTER 2100-PROCESS-RECORD TO 2120-PROCESS-DETAIL.
     GO TO 2199-EXIT.
*
 2120-PROCESS-DETAIL.
* code to process a detail record 
     GO TO 2199-EXIT.
...
*
 2199-EXIT.
     EXIT.
```

In my mind, the flow is like this:

```
     PERFORM 2100-PROCESS-RECORD THRU 2199-EXIT.
...
 2100-PROCESS-RECORD. 
     GO TO 2110-PROCESS-HEADER.
*
 2110-PROCESS-HEADER.
* code to process a file header
     ALTER 2100-PROCESS-RECORD TO 2120-PROCESS-DETAIL.
     GO TO 2199-EXIT.

 2199-EXIT.
     EXIT.
```

If ALTER is to change the destination of a GO-TO, how can it be useful if the GO-TO was already executed and the program exited?

Comment: did you Google "cobol exit"? I've updated my answer.

Comment: ALTER was depreciated with the COBOL 85 standard (someting over 25 years ago). If you ever come across ALTER in "the wild" you are looking at some very old code. ALTER only had a "life" during the 50's and early 60's, I would not spend a lot of time studying it.

Answer (score 5):

http://home.swbell.net/mck9/cobol/style/alter.html explains it. you're correct for the first execution, but on *subsequent* runs the behavior is changed:

"The first time we execute the PERFORM, control passes through 2110-PROCESS-HEADER. However, the ALTER at the end of that paragraph changes the destination of the GO TO in 2100-PROCESS-RECORD. As a result, on all subsequent executions of the PERFORM, control does not pass through 2110-PROCESS-HEADER. It passes through 2120-PROCESS-DETAIL instead.

"The potential for confusion is obvious. The altered GO TO does not go where it claims to go -- instead, it goes to a place specified in some remote piece of code. To understand how the code works you need to know that the ALTER is present, and you need to know all the circumstances which execute the ALTER."

it's called self-modifying code, and it's very hard to understand and debug. for some light reading before bed, I recommend http://www.pbm.com/~lindahl/mel.html the story of Mel.

in Cobol, the EXIT statement does *not* mean "exit the program": http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref.doc/evfeb4ls124.htm

Comment: PERFORM 2100-PROCESS-RECORD THRU 2199-EXIT Only execute once, doesn't it?

Comment: if it does, no problem. but chances are there are many records, and all will need processing.

Comment: are you just learning COBOL? the EXIT statement doesn't mean what it does in many other languages.

Comment: So, is Exit does nothing, or Exit let the program know that is the end of the paragraph, and transfer the control back to the statement next to PERFORM?

Comment: @jcomeau Ha! The missing +1 was not a software issue ... just an attention deficit. Solved :)

Comment: @gunbuster363 I'm not a COBOL programmer myself, but the documentation indicates that when control reaches the named paragraph of the EXIT, if it were a called procedure (with PERFORM) then it returns to the PROCEDURE division; otherwise it is a no-op, and control passes through it.

Comment: @gunbuster363. EXIT is a do nothing (no-op) statement used to hang a label on (paragraph name), which in turn is a standard place for a GO TO target. There is a long history to EXIT. Modern COBOL really doesn't need it (don't use GO and you should ever need an EXIT statement). Again modern cobol (at least since 1985) has all of the control structures you need for GOTOless programming.